# how to INSERT INTO JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join, insert, insert-into

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]

Product images into numbers are included.
I want to save [screen]shots in product_images.
How should I save product_id?

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO product_images 
            (image_name = '".$image_name."', 
             created = '".$time."', 
             product_id = '".$id."') 

             (SELECT image_name, created, product_id 
              FROM product_images 
                LEFT JOIN products ON 
                      product_images.product_id = products.'".$id."')
            ");
```

Comment: **No. No. No. No. No.**  1) The `mysql_` interface is deprecated, use the mysqli or PDO interface. 2) generate the SQL text into a variable, so you can echo/var_dump (for debugging) before submitting to the database. 3) SQL syntax is invalid for an INSERT statement. Do this `INSERT (col1,col2,col3) SELECT ...` , no equals signs or values in the column list. 4) code appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection; potentially unsafe values need to be properly escaped, or, preferred pattern is *prepared statement* with *bind placeholders*. 5) not allowed to reference same table in INSERT and SELECT;

Comment: Made the question less terse - should be easier to follow :-)

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily forgetting about the fact you should not be using the mysql_ functions anymore...

You queries are all wrong:

First this is the syntax for an insert

```
INSERT INTO product_images 
        (image_name, created, product_id)
 VALUES ('$image_name', '$time', $id)
```

Second you cannot run 2 queries through the same `mysql_query()` statement so you need to do 2 seperate calls and get your select query syntax correct

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO product_images 
             (image_name, created, product_id)
      VALUES ('$image_name', '$time', $id)";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if ( ! $result ) {
    // the insert failed 
}

$sql = "SELECT image_name, created, product_id 
        FROM product_images 
           LEFT JOIN products ON 
                product_images.product_id = products.id
        WHERE
          products.id = $id";
$result = sql_query($sql);
if ( ! $result ) {
    // the select failed
} 

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
    // process each row returned by the select query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
{

```
$uploaddir = "public/uploads/"; //a directory inside
foreach ($_FILES['photos']['name'] as $name => $value)
{

    $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['photos']['name'][$name]);
    $size=filesize($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$name]);
    //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
      $ext = getExtension($filename);
      $ext = strtolower($ext);

     if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
     {
       if ($size < (MAX_SIZE*1024))
       {
       $image_name=time().$filename;
       echo "<img src='".$uploaddir.$image_name."' class='imgList'>";
       $newname=$uploaddir.$image_name;

       if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$name], $newname)) 
       {
       $time=time();
       $last_ID = mysql_insert_id();
       mysql_query("INSERT INTO product_images(image_name,product_id,created) VALUES('$image_name','$session_id','$time')");
       }
       else
       {
        echo '<span class="imgList">You have exceeded the size limit! so moving unsuccessful! </span>';
        }

       }
       else
       {
        echo '<span class="imgList">You have exceeded the size limit!</span>';

       }

      }
      else
     { 
        echo '<span class="imgList">Unknown extension!</span>';

     }

 }
```

}